# Logging a Get-Item on Powershell

Tags: powershell, logging, robocopy, powershell-cmdlet

I wanted to know if there's an easy way to log all successful transferred items to a .txt file. I would like to create the .txt file and list all the files that are being transferred and updating it afterwards if it is used again (like on robocopy / log+)?

Current:

```
$loc1 = "C:\Users\user1\Documents\test2\*"

$loc2 = "C:\Users\user1\Documents\test2" 

Move-Item $loc1 $loc2 -force
```

Comment: `robocopy` works in PowerShell too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -PassThru at the end of Move-Item. It will return a FileInfo object (same as returned by Get-ChildItem) for each item moved:

```
$itemsMoved = Move-Item test.* E:\Scratch\t2 -PassThru
$itemsMoved | Select-Object FullName | Add-content c:\temp\copy.log
```

Comment: Is there a way to concat to just to show the name of the file? not the whole directory?

Comment: Yes, just use "Name" instead of "FullName" in the Select-Object clause.

Comment: Could I ask where you get the syntax for Select-Object? like Name, FullName etc. because when i try to auto complete it (Tab) doesnt show me all the options

and is there a way to take out the ("@{Name=") from @{Name=test.txt} to just show test.txt  

Thank you for answering my questions really appreciate it!

Comment: Since Move-Item passes through FileInfo objects, you can either look up MSDN's documentation on FileInfo, or you can do this:  

Get-ChildItem test.* | Get-Member -MemberType Property

This will show all the properties that you can use directly with Select-Object.

Answer (score 0):

some options :

use the -`verbose` switch

if you have powershell V3  you can use the 'redirect everything' operator `*>`

```
Move-Item $loc1 $loc2 -force -Verbose *> c:\temp\copy.log
```

you can also use `start-transcript`

```
Start-Transcript -Path C:\temp\cp.log
Move-Item $loc1 $loc2 -force -Verbose
Stop-Transcript
```

or use a foreach-object

```
$loc1 |%{
    cp $_.FullName $loc2;
    if ($? -eq $true){ #copy ok
        echo "file copied : $($_.name)">>c:\temp\copy.log 
    }
}
```